# Installation crash from trying to overwrite files

Tags: system-installation, crash

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an old Acer Aspire One D150-1Bw. I am installing ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-i386 from a USB stick.

I keep receiving an error message (see link below) when installing the OS. When I press continue the installer then crashes (displays crash message).

Does anyone know a solution to this problem, bearing in mind I am a beginner?

[image]

Comment: Did you do anything to the ISO? (like make a custom install and add packages or download it from a non-official location?)

Comment: did you try installing the OS without formatting the partition? or was there a failed installation before this one? If so, backup what ever data is on the partition, format the partition and try installing from a Fresh USB boot disk which is made from an ISO from canonical made with `unetbootin`.

Comment: @endrias, yep. There was a failed installation before. Freshly formatted USB fixed it. :)

Comment: @Rinzwind. It was an official ISO with no modifications but I think the USB had not been formatted correctly. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to download the ISO again and recreate the installer.

When you search your message these bug reports show up: [bug #1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1514422) and [bug #2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1540159) (see comment #5). Both have been closed automatically with this message:

> Reviewing your installation log file it appears that your installation media contains some extra data which is causing the installation to fail. The standard Ubuntu installation media (and that of supported derivatives) does not include this data and will not fail in this way, so it must be an issue with the way your installation media was prepared. Subsequently, this bug report is Invalid. However, to resolve the issue should try fully erasing the USB drive which contains the installer before recreating it. Thanks and good luck!
>
> [This is an automated message. I apologize if it reached you inappropriately; please just reply to this message indicating so.]

[Bug #3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1480318) has this comment ...

> You have dirty installation media containing a mix of debian and ubuntu. You need to format the installation medium before preparing it for use to install a new OS.

Comment: Thanks, did the trick! I guess the USB didn't format correctly the first time.

Comment: Happy to see it fixed. Have fun with Ubuntu